# Ensure URL points to a real location?

Tags: php, url, exists

I've got this little CMS thing going, and the user has the ability to preview the post before submitting. I'd like to have a feature that checks whether a URL entered is valid (I.E. points to a resource that exists, not whether it's in the correct format or not). Preferably, I'd like to do it with JavaScript (I don't have to use AJAX and PHP then), but PHP is fine.

Can someone point me towards a way of doing this? Just in case, I want a yes/no response from something like running the UNIX `ping` command. I don't care about what's at the other end of the URL, just whether it actually points to something navigable.

Thanks,

James

Comment: Use cURL to send a HEAD request.  You'll need to set aggressive timeouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could simply use fopen to see if the url will work ... of course, this could be resource overkill depending on how often you are doing it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Alternately, you can use a jquery plugin:

http://binarykitten.me.uk/dev/jq-plugins/88-jquery-plugin-ajax-head-request.html

An alternate, and probably the easiest way which isn't live ... but you can use jquery to call another php script that implements it:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php

Comment: Thanks for the response sdolgy. I've opted for the jQuery path, but would you mind telling me how I'd go about getting that plugin to return with a true/false value, so I can choose whether to display a message or not? Thanks very much.

Comment: if you iterate through the headers and look for the specific http status code 200 = OK, 304 = cached, etc.  here's a list of the codes:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Thanks for that, however, the only headers I got returned where these: Date:--:Thu, 21 Apr 2011 20:33:09 GMT
Server:--:Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By:--:PHP/5.3.5-1ubuntu7
Expires:--:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control:--:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma:--:no-cache
Vary:--:Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding:--:gzip
Content-Length:--:2860
Keep-Alive:--:timeout=15, max=95
Connection:--:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:--:text/html
Please excuse the absence of line breaks :-(

Comment: no problem.  try a location that doesn't exist.  compare the differences?  it should be the first line in the response header.  http://web-sniffer.net/ ..

Comment: By the way, the header status below 399 is usually a good indication, so your code would look like: `if(status>399)alert("error");`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help people. I finally settled on checking whether `headers.Expires` has a value or not, which is simple yet works well enough.

Answer (score 1):

Load it into a new `img` object, and see what the response is. Since you're not actually displaying the image, the fact that you may be loading up plain text or other non-image data is mostly irrelevant, you just want to see what the HTTP status code for the image request is.

The benefit is that if a malicious user tries to load in a URL that points to an obscenely large file, they'd only DoS themselves, as the request would go out from their browser and not your server. On the down side, nothing would stop them from spoofing a proper response and STILL put in that large-size resource and submit the form anyways.